# CrmServiceClient Last known error : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

CrmServiceClient Last known error :  One or more errors occurred. => An error occurred while sending the request. => The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. => Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.ERROR REQUESTING Token FROM THE Authentication context
ERROR REQUESTING Token FROM THE Authentication contextNeed a non-empty authority
Parameter name: AuthorityUnable to connect to CRM: Need a non-empty authority
Parameter name: Authority
Need a non-empty authority
Parameter name: AuthorityUnable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM

Answer (score 0):

One will see this error because of TLS.
I was stuck with the online connectivity. I created a reusable library in .Net Framework 4.7.2.
It works great from my unit test projects.
When I imported it as a NuGet package in my actual project, I keept seeing the above error, it work good for On-premise with AuthyType "AD" but failed to connect CRM online.

The reason behind this is my current project runtime targetframework is set to 4.5.2. After changing it to  
    
it started working as expected.
Reference links: 
1) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051700
2) https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/383948/client-secret-connection-string-for-sdk-access

Comment: Encountering this error due to a TLS issue is possible even when targeting .NET 4.7+. In that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74738094/1667351) answer may help.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked in my case

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;